# Add a custom button without close odoo 9 wizard?

Tags: odoo, wizard

Good day,

I've been working on the lot and serial number module in odoo 9.

I changed the sequence that the module has as default and I substituted it with the generation of an UUID, but when I call this component in the received items part, when I click on the button that generates the UUID the app suddenly returns to the window that I used to call it without letting me to save the UUID that I generated.

Here's my code:

```
class stock_production_lot(osv.osv):
_name = 'stock.production.lot'
_inherit = ['mail.thread']
_description = 'Lot/Serial'

_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Serial Number', required=True, help="Unique Serial Number"),
    'x_num_serie_': fields.char('No. de serie', required=False, help="No. de serie del producto"),
    'ref': fields.char('Internal Reference', help="Internal reference number in case it differs from the manufacturer's serial number"),
    'product_id': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Product', required=True, domain=[('type', 'in', ['product', 'consu'])]),
    'quant_ids': fields.one2many('stock.quant', 'lot_id', 'Quants', readonly=True),
    'create_date': fields.datetime('Creation Date'),
}

_defaults = {
    'name': lambda x, y, z, c: x.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_code(y, z, 'stock.lot.serial'),
    'x_num_serie_':None,
    'product_id': lambda x, y, z, c: c.get('product_id', False),
}
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_ref_uniq', 'unique (name, product_id)', 'The combination of serial number and product must be unique !'),
]        

def action_traceability(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ It traces the information of lots
    @param self: The object pointer.
    @param cr: A database cursor
    @param uid: ID of the user currently logged in
    @param ids: List of IDs selected
    @param context: A standard dictionary
    @return: A dictionary of values
    """
    quant_obj = self.pool.get("stock.quant")
    quants = quant_obj.search(cr, uid, [('lot_id', 'in', ids)], context=context)
    moves = set()
    for quant in quant_obj.browse(cr, uid, quants, context=context):
        moves |= {move.id for move in quant.history_ids}
    if moves:
        return {
            'domain': "[('id','in',[" + ','.join(map(str, list(moves))) + "])]",
            'name': _('Traceability'),
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'context': {'tree_view_ref': 'stock.view_move_tree'},
            'res_model': 'stock.move',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                }
    return False


def action_generate_uuid(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    print "< action_generate_uuid >"
    _uuid = (uuid.uuid1()).hex

    obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context)

    print "< obj.name >",obj.name

    for item in self.browse(cr, uid, ids,context=context):

        if item.name:                
            item.name = _uuid 
            item.x_num_serie_ = _uuid
            print "< name >",item.name
            print "< x_num_serie_>",item.x_num_serie_

        else:
            print "< falta un elemento >"

    return None
```

I'll really appreciate any idea on what is happening and how can I avoid it.

Best regards,

Alain

Answer (score 2):

The default behaviour is to close upon the pressing of any button and execution of the function associated with the button. The work around is to have the button execute a function and then return an action bringing up the exact same wizard.

You can set context to open the wizard again with all the form values populated.

Here is an example:

```
class MyWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'myaddon.mywizard'

    def _get_default_char(self):
        return self._context.get('mychar',"")

    mychar = fields.Char(string="My Char", default=_get_default_char)

    @api.multi
    def my_button(self):
        # Execute Function Here
        # reload wizard with context

        return {
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'myaddon.mywizard',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': self.id,
            'context': '{"default_mychar":'HELLO WORLD'}',
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing knowledge!

Comment: Oh, one thing I just noticed in my posting. When pre-populating fields in a form view in Odoo you pass a context object with a syntax like this {"default_{{your_field_name}}":"value"} notice the "default" in front of your field name. I think I missed this originally in my posting and it has since been updated.